# Adding table style in vba

Tags: vba, email, html-table, userform

How to add the table style in the code so that it will show like this as shown in the picture? [table style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t63jV.png) I tried to modify it but it doesn't look what I expected.

```
Private Function getItems(lb As MSForms.ListBox) As String
    Dim row, col As Long
    Dim i      As String, items As String
    Dim total  As Double

    'check if listbox is empty
    If Me.ListboxResult.ListCount = 0 Then
        getItems = ""
        Exit Function
    End If
    'table view
    items = "<table border='1' style='width: 50%'><tr><th style = 'text-align:left;'>Type</th><th style = 'text-align:left;'>Item</th><th style = 'text-align:left;'>Quantity</th><th style = 'text-align:left;'>Unit</th></tr>"
    
    With lb
        total = 0
        For row = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            i = "<tr>"
            
            'add each cell to the row
            i = i & "<td style= 'border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse' >" & .Column(0, row) & "</td>"
            i = i & "<td style= 'border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;'>" & .Column(1, row) & "</td>"
            i = i & "<td style='border: 1px solid black; text-align: right;  border-collapse: collapse'>" & .Column(2, row) & "</td>"
            i = i & "<td style='border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse'>" & .Column(3, row) & "</td>"
            
            i = i & "</tr>"                       'end the row
            items = items & i
            i = ""
            total = total + CDbl(.Column(2, row))
        Next row
        i = "<tr><td style='border: none; border-collapse: collapse'></td><td style='border: none; border-collapse: collapse'></td><td style='text-align: right; border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse'> <b>Total:</b>  " & CStr(total) & "</td></tr>"
        items = items & i
    End With
    
    items = items & "</table>"
    getItems = items
    
End Function
```

This is how I used in the item section:

```
Private Sub submit(ByVal items As String)         'send email
    Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Source As String

    Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application        'directly create a new instance, a reference has to be set in Outlook Object Library
    'Set EmailApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'create a new instance of the Outlook Application, does not require a reference to be set in the environment
    Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    With EmailItem
        .To = "abc@email.com"
        .Subject = "Stationery Request"
        '.Body = "Please see the ordering details below for your reference:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & items & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Total: " & Me.TxtboxTotal.Value
        
        '.HTMLBody = "Dear xxxx,<br><br>" & vbNewLine & "Please see the order details below for your reference:<br><br>" & items & "<br> <br> Regards, <br>" & "Name"
        .HTMLBody = "Please see the order details below for your reference:<br><br>" & items
        'Source = ThisWorkbook.FullName
        '.Attachments.Add Source
        .Display
        '.Send
    End With
End Sub
```

This is what I have for the output [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlvGx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is html/css problem, not vba problem.

Your HTML structure is bad : you should add header and footer, add the last cell, merge in the footer the first two cells.

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
        thead {
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
        }
        tbody {
            text-align: start;
        }
        tfoot {
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .total_value {
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        table {
            border-top: 2px solid #dddddd;
            border-left: 2px solid #dddddd;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #888888;
            border-right: 2px solid #888888;
        }
        th, td {
            border-top: 2px solid #888888;
            border-left: 2px solid #888888;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
            border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
            
            padding: 2px 5px;
        }
            </style>
        </head>
    
        <body>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Unit</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>General</td>
                        <td>Letter Opener</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>pc(s)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>aaa aaa</td>
                        <td>bbb bbb</td>
                        <td>ccc cccc</td>
                        <td>ddd dddd dddd</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>aaa aaa aaa aaaaa</td>
                        <td>bbb bbb</td>
                        <td>ccc cccc cccc ccccc</td>
                        <td>ddd</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Total</th>
                        <th class="total_value">11</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Your table style is ugly, you should use this CSS style:

```css
thead,tfoot {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
tbody {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: start;
}
.total_value {
    font-weight: normal;
}

th, td {
    padding: 5px 5px;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid #009977;
}

tbody tr {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #333333;
}      

thead,tfoot tr {
    background-color: #22bb22;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Unit</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>General</td>
          <td>Letter Opener</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>pc(s)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>aaa aaa</td>
          <td>bbb bbb</td>
          <td>ccc cccc</td>
          <td>ddd dddd dddd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>aaa aaa aaa aaaaa</td>
          <td>bbb bbb</td>
          <td>ccc cccc cccc ccccc</td>
          <td>ddd</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Total</th>
          <th class="total_value">11</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

VBA code to generate table HTML code:

```
Private Function getItems(colItems As Collection) As String
    Dim row, col As Long
    Dim i      As String, html As String
    Dim total  As Double
    Dim item As Variant

    'check if listbox is empty
    If colItems.Count = 0 Then
        getItems = ""
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    'table view
    html = "<table>" & vbCrLf
    
    ' add head table
    html = html & "<thead><tr><th>Type</th><th>Item</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Unit</th></tr></thead>" & vbCrLf
            
    
    ' add body table
    html = html & "<tbody>" & vbCrLf 'start of body
    total = 0
    For Each item In colItems
        i = "<tr>" 'start of row
        
        'add each cell to the row
        i = i & "<td>" & item(0) & "</td>"
        i = i & "<td>" & item(1) & "</td>"
        i = i & "<td>" & item(2) & "</td>"
        i = i & "<td>" & item(3) & "</td>"
        
        i = i & "</tr>" & vbCrLf 'end the row
        html = html & i

        total = total + CDbl(item(2))
    Next item
    html = html & "</tbody>" & vbCrLf 'end of body

    ' add footer table
    html = html & "<tfoot><tr><th colspan=""2"">Total</th><th class=""total_value"">" + CStr(total) + "</th><th></th></tr></tfoot>" & vbCrLf
        
    html = html & "</table>" & vbCrLf 'end of table
    getItems = html
    
End Function
```

You must add CCS style ("style" tag content) at the beginning of your email message... or integrate CCS code in HTML code by using the "style" property in each HTML tag but it is very heavy...
But for maximum compatibility with email clients, Microsoft recommends embedding the CCS code in HTML tags. The best solution for compatibility is not to use CSS at all.
For exemple, "box-shadow" CSS property doesn't work with outlook. Use the verst version of CSS for compatibility.

Exemple to generate CSS code for the header of your HTML message:

```
Private Function getCssStyle() As String
    Dim css As String
    
css = "thead,tfoot {" & vbCrLf _
    & " font-weight: bold;" & vbCrLf _
    & " text-align: center;" & vbCrLf _
    & "}" & vbCrLf _
    & "tbody {" & vbCrLf _
    & " font-weight: normal;" & vbCrLf _
    & " text-align: start;" & vbCrLf _
    & "}" & vbCrLf _
    & ".total_value {" & vbCrLf _
    & " font-weight: normal;" & vbCrLf _
    & "}" & vbCrLf _
    & "th, td {" & vbCrLf _
    & " padding: 5px 5px;" & vbCrLf _
    & "}" & vbCrLf _
    & "td {" & vbCrLf

' you must split the CSS because you can set infinite number of line in VBA
css = css & "   border: 1px solid #dddddd;" & vbCrLf _
    & "}" & vbCrLf _
    & "table {" & vbCrLf _
    & " border-collapse: collapse;" & vbCrLf _
    & " border: 2px solid #009977;" & vbCrLf _
    & "}" & vbCrLf _
    & "tbody tr {" & vbCrLf _
    & " background-color: #ffffff;" & vbCrLf _
    & " color: #333333;" & vbCrLf _
    & "}" & vbCrLf _
    & "thead,tfoot tr {" & vbCrLf _
    & " background-color: #22bb22;" & vbCrLf _
    & " color: #ffffff;" & vbCrLf _
    & "}" & vbCrLf
    
    getCssStyle = css
End Function
```

To create your entire message and make email:

```
Private Sub submit(htmlMessage As String) 'send email
    Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Source As String

    Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application        'directly create a new instance, a reference has to be set in Outlook Object Library
    Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    With EmailItem
        .To = "abc@email.com"
        .Subject = "Stationery Request"
        .HTMLBody = htmlMessage
        .Display
    End With
End Sub

Sub Run()
    Dim html As String
    Load UserForm1

    html = "<html><head><style>" & getCssStyle() & "</style></head>" & vbCrLf
    html = html & "<body>" & getItems(UserForm1.ListBox1) & "</body></html>"

    submit (html)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm Im doing it in VBA with HTML/CSS...

Comment: How getItems() is called in your application? CSS style (<style> tag) should be integrated once at the beginning of your output file. Table HTML code (<table> tag) should be integrated in getItems()

Comment: Like this: ```Dim items  As String: items = getItems(Me.ListboxResult)```

Comment: How "items" variable is used?

Comment: I just used it in the email section

Comment: How should I call the css function?

Comment: I updated my message (to see htmlMessage) : is it good for you?

Comment: There isn't any border in the table for some reason. Should I show you the code?

Comment: if you paste the value of htmlMessage in a text file with the name "index.htm" and after you open it with webrowser : there is no border ? Can you show value of htmlMessage ?

Comment: Yeah but if I remove the value, i cant see the ones I selected in the userform

Comment: I do some tests, the CSS property "box-shadow" isn't not supported by outlook : it is the problem

Comment: I edited my post : now, it should work for you

Comment: the outlook still can't display the border. Should I show you the file?

Comment: test file : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f125f34d0d2f69c2f2217f356fd6b01620231123075359/e8eab4

Comment: should I show you my file? Cuz Im not sure what happened to the program

Comment: yes you should.

Comment: Please go to this link for my file: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AoG54UAwiBOuh5UB3mPwPAD0V-1-gw?e=fSaQa0

Comment: You don't use MSForms.ListBox but Collection : your getItems function is wrong... fix it. And delete your code with "strHTML" and replace it the code by my code in Run function (without lines : Load and submit)

Comment: Is it like ```Private Function html(lb As Collection) As String``` and ```Dim html  As String: html = html(Me.ListboxResult)```? I need the strHTML for the Excel sheet, not the userform

Comment: ... use my getItems function

Comment: You must set the code in Excel sheet

Comment: Please see the file here: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AoG54UAwiBOuh5UD8lhQdJKuo8mKIQ?e=QchZos I think I changed almost everything but still cant see the border. I'll change the part in the excel sheet later.